# User object doesn't seem to be fully loaded when trying to do route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In Meteor with IronRouter I'm trying to check that the users email address is verified, however when I check it, sometimes the "emails" array on user isn't there when I'm trying to work out in the route where to go.  If I ask after routing then the emails array is there.   Sometimes it's also there when routing.  So I'm assuming the user isn't synched properly when I'm trying to use it in the route, so I'm wondering how to make iron router wait till the user is fully loaded.

```
function verifiedUser() {
    if(!Meteor.user().emails)   return false;
    if(!Meteor.user().emails[0]) return false;
    return Meteor.user().emails[0].verified;
}

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('app', {
    path: '/',    
     onBeforeAction: function() {
      if(Meteor.user())
      {
        if(verifiedUser()) {
          Router.go('coolstuff');
        }
      else { 
         Router.go('email');
      }
    }
   })
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend showing the code for your route and the definition of `verifiedUser`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [{{currentUser}}](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_currentuser) instead of using your own `verifiedUser()` function. Also, it seems that [fast-render](http://meteorhacks.com/instant-login-for-meteor-with-fast-render.html) can solve your problem.

Comment: no, I can't, the user can login with facebook, but the verified user is checking for a verified email address